# Mockito thenReturn not working, but "when" works

Tags: java, mockito

I'm testing a class using a mockito Spy

```
@Spy UserRepository userRepositoryMock;
```

if I stub it with a when expression, it works

```
when(userRepositoryMock.findById(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(user1));
```

But I want to understand why the other syntax, doReturn does not work:

```
doReturn(Optional.of(user1)).when(userRepositoryMock.findById(anyString()));
```

using doReturn spits out the following error message

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at io.onq.web.controller.api.user.UserUnitTest.testUserlistOktaStateChange(UserUnitTest.java:110)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
```

Any ideas why that fails?

Comment: have you tried this? (please check the difference on the parenthesis)
    doReturn(Optional.of(user1)).when(userRepositoryMock).findById(anyString()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Carlos's comment, when you use doReturn() the code should look like

```
Mockito.doReturn(activity).when(dao).getActivity("0001");
```

So when we check your code we see that you missed ")" after spy/mock Object.
So your stub should look like:

```
doReturn(Optional.of(user1)).when(userRepositoryMock).findById(anyString()));
```